# list of supported chars for current LaTeX configuration

Tags: fonts, symbols, accents, characters

I am calling pdfLaTeX with text entered in a web form. I would like to replace important chars not supported by LaTeX with the right LaTeX command.

How can I get a list of chars supported by LaTeX so that I can program replacements for chars which I think are important? The method should include the usepackage commands I am about to have in my document because e.g. the `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` command is extending the list of supported chars.

I am using the TeX Live distribution, provided by the package manager of Ubuntu.

Comment: @Stephan: A lot of chars are not directly enabled if you load inputenc e.g. the euro, but for everyone you could add a suitable definition.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Oh, wow. I didn't know that. Strange. Thanks for clarifying. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With the `utf8` option, `inputenc` loads (if existent) a configuration file called `<enc>def.dfu` for every output encoding declared in the document; for example, with

```
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
```

the loaded configuration file will be `t1enc.dfu`. It's really irrelevant whether `fontenc` is called before or after `inputenc`, but I prefer to have this "cleaner" order.

If the `fontenc` package is not loaded, very few Unicode points are activated, as results clearly from `ot1enc.dfu`.

However the list of supported Unicode characters can be extended either by declarations such as

```
\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{201D}{\textquotedblright}
```

where the hexadecimal code is given together with a suitable definition for the character, or by the similar

```
\usepackage{newunicodechar}
\newunicodechar{”}{\textquotedblright}
```

which has the advantage that one doesn't need to hunt through the code tables to find the correct number.

A rather rough way to show what a `.dfu` file contains is to run LaTeX on the following file

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T2A,TS1,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\parindent=0pt
\newcommand{\showdfu}[1]{%
  \section{Encoding #1}
  \begingroup\makeatletter
  \renewcommand\DeclareUnicodeCharacter[2]{%
    \par Code point: \texttt{##1}, Meaning: \texttt{\detokenize{##2}}, character: {\fontencoding{#1}\selectfont##2}}%
  \nonstopmode\lowercase{\input{#1enc.dfu}}
  \endgroup
}

\begin{document}

\showdfu{T1}
\showdfu{T2A}
\showdfu{TS1}

\end{document}
```

The encodings should be loaded beforehand, as shown in the example.

Comment: So with output encoding T1 and input encoding utf8 the resulting supported input characters will be the ASCII chars plus the Unicode chars defined in `t1enc.dfu`?

Comment: @PascalRosin Yes, that's basically what you get. A list of the characters and their "LaTeX Internal Character Representation" is available in the LaTeX companion.

Comment: wow, that example in the last update is very helpful. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Hava a look at [The Comprehensive Latex Symbol List](https://ctan.org/tex-archive/info/symbols/comprehensive/symbols-a4.pdf)  (164 pages) were you'll find nearly every symbol you want to set in LaTeX.